# How to make a multi layer horizontal recyclerview or gridlayout?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, multi-layer

I am novice to android studio and I want to make a 2 or 3 layer of cardview in one recyclerview or gridlayout/gridview that can scroll horizontally, but I can't find any tutorial about it. Can someone please help me on how can i make it.[image]

Basically the idea is when the user scrolled to the left, both or all the layers of products will slide at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a new `OnScrollListener` to be able to detect how much you scrolled your recycler view by using `onScrolled` callback method.

and then you need to pass dx and dx int values to your another Recyclerview in order to scroll it simultaneously with your dragged Recyclerview

your new onScrollListener should seems like below

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            scrollAllRecyclerView(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        private void scrollAllRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

               scroll(dx, dy)
            }
        }

        private void scroll(int dx, int dy) {
            recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
            recyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(this);
        }
```

**anotherRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy);**

Comment: Hi sir thank your for your comment! But can you please upload the whole class and the xml file example. I really still don't understand the process of doing the recyclerview. It would be a pleasure to me and I will accept your Answer right away. Thank you so much!

Comment: ok then you should understand the basics of recyclerview & adapter class

Comment: Luckily I understand now the basics of adapters and models and now I am taking the recyclerview. Thank you so much!

Comment: so you should add this new created OnScrollListener into your all recycler views and you should pass these dx, dy values between recylerviews interchangeably

Comment: all you need to do is passing dx and dy values to another recylerview and then scroll each recylerview by using scrollBy method as shown at above

Comment: So i need 2 recyclerviews sir?

Comment: @Mr.Baks yeap exactly

Comment: Also should I add this OnscrollListener in my "MainActivity" not the Adapter?

Comment: So basically the purpose of this method was to connect the 2 recyclerview so when the user scroll any of that recyclerview it will scroll the other one?

Comment: yes exactly, we're just passing x and y position of dragged recyclerview to be able to scroll another recycler view simultaneously

Comment: And sir lastly, Where should i place the other recyclerview? On top of another?

Comment: @Mr.Baks yes exactly

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I will now try it.